# Why do I always get 0 records as output while reading from dtap:// hive table in Presto?

Tags: hive, presto, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to run Presto with Hive (all version details below) on CDH 5.14.2
Surprisingly, I get 0 records as output when I run any select query on any table. When I do select * on any table, I just get list of all fields, again no data.
All the tables are external hive tables with data in parquet format

- Hive 1.1.0
- Presto 0.223, also 0.219

Check the server.log file in Presto installation, no ERROR or WARN messages there

Also tried this same installation with Presto 0.219, same case

presto:sample_db> select count(*) from tableName;

```
_col0
-------
     0
(1 row)

Query 20190925_125900_00005_8tzp2, FINISHED, 1 node
Splits: 18 total, 18 done (100.00%)
0:01 [0 rows, 0B] [0 rows/s, 0B/s]
```

Output of DESCRIBE FORMATTED tablename --

```
# col_name              data_type               comment

column1             string
column2             string
column3             string
column4             decimal(6,0)
column5             timestamp

# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type               comment

active                  string

# Detailed Table Information
Database:               db_name
Owner:                  cloudera-vivek
CreateTime:             Sun Nov 25 03:23:06 GMT 2018
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN
Protect Mode:           None
Retention:              0
Location:               dtap://dbname/tablename
Table Type:             EXTERNAL_TABLE
Table Parameters:
        EXTERNAL                TRUE
        STATS_GENERATED_VIA_STATS_TASK  true
        numPartitions           2
        numRows                 4142
        transient_lastDdlTime   1543116186

# Storage Information
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat
Compressed:             No
Num Buckets:            -1
Bucket Columns:         []
Sort Columns:           []
Storage Desc Params:
        serialization.format    1
Time taken: 0.919 seconds, Fetched: 40 row(s)
```

Could this be because of some version mismatch between Hive and Presto? I couldn't find anything like this in Presto release notes
Any other .jar or config files which needs to be added while setup?

Very much appreciate your help

Comment: check the field delimiters and line terminators, they should be specified in `create table`

Comment: I have checked `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` and also `DESCRIBE EXTENDED <tablename>` it doesn't show **field.delim** anywhere. Am assuming **row format delimited fields terminated by** wasn't specified while creating table (as it wasn't created by me)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the msck repair table table-name as mentioned here: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/4109 ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Rupam. I have tried MSCK REPAIR TABLE db_name.table_name; didn't work

Comment: Can you please share the output of "DESCRIBE FORMATTED table" in Hive? Also, are you able to see the correct output if you do "select * from table" in Hive?

Comment: I have updated that in the question asked above. Please note, data is access via dtap (https://bluedata.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/220223188-DataTap-Overview), not directly from HDFS

Comment: Can you also share "SHOW PARTITIONS tablename" in Hive?

Comment: May be you need to run "ALTER TABLE tablename RECOVER PARTITIONS"

Comment: output of SHOW PARTITIONS <tableName>partition
1 active=0
2 active=1

Comment: I am unable to run ALTER TABLE <TableName> RECOVER PARTITIONS, getting error `Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 10:72 cannot recognize input near 'RECOVER' 'PARTITIONS' '<EOF>' in alter table statement`